# Yii Multiple Scenario based client validations

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am creating a form using Yii's activeForm.

All aspects of the form are working except that the client side validation does not take care of scenarios.

I would like it if I can get the client validations working based on scenarios.

Below mentioned is the partial code for the form

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'errorMessageCssClass' => 'has-error',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'role' => 'form',
        'id' => 'payment-form',
    ),
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'id' => 'payment-form',
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'errorCssClass' => 'has-error',
        'successCssClass' => 'has-success',
        'inputContainer' => '.form-group',
        'validateOnChange' => true,
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI the scenario validation is done when the data is pushed to the model, where we have defined the scenarios for the validation. So if you want to validate on client side, the only way is to use "JAVASCRIPT", Or through the ajax, which you have turned off enable the ajax validation `'enableAjaxValidation' => true,` to get the client validation using ajax.

Comment: Yes, I agree but when it is turned on for each field it will send a request to the server, and can be a little slow at time for each key press, I have seen the code generated by Yii and when ajax returns it comes back with the scenario based client validation and after that it does not do an ajax request, it would be great if some how yii did this at the very beginning

Comment: If you are that much concern about the time then use javascript client side validation, keeping the scenarios in your mind